# Using RSpec to test a Retry RestClient

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, rest-client

I'm using Oauth so what I do is store `access_token` and `refresh token` at `User` table, I create some classes to do this. In the `Create` class I do the normal functionality of the code (create records on the integration). The `access_token` expire at 1 hour, so intead of schedule an `active job` to refresh that token at that time I decided to do `Refresh.new(user).call` to request a new `access_token` and `refresh_token`.

I know that code works, because I've tested on live and I'm getting the new token when the access_token is expired. But I want to do a rspec test for this.

part of my **rspec test**:.

```rb
context 'when token is expired' do
  it 'request a refresh token and retry' do
    old_key = user.access_token
    allow(RestClient)
      .to receive(:post)
      .and_raise(RestClient::Unauthorized).once
    expect { Create.new.call }.to change { user.reload.access_token }.from(old_key)
  end
end
```

**This is the response:**

```
(RestClient).post(# data)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 2 times with arguments: (# data)
```

**This is my code:**

**Create.rb**

```rb
class Create
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
    @refresh_token = user&.refresh_token
    @access_token = user&.access_token
    @logger = Rails.logger
    @message = Crm::Message.new(self.class, 'User', user&.id)
  end

  def call
    # validations
    create_contact
  rescue RestClient::Unauthorized => ex
    retry if Refresh.new(user).call
  rescue RestClient::ExceptionWithResponse => ex
    logger.error(@message.api_error(ex))
    raise
  end

  private

  attr_reader :user, :logger, :access_token, :refresh_token

  def create_contact
    response = RestClient.post(
      url, contact_params, contact_headers
    )
    logger.info(@message.api_response(response))
  end
end
```

**Refresh.rb**

```rb
class Refresh
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
    @refresh_token = user&.refresh_token
    @access_token = user&.access_token
    @logger = Rails.logger
    @message = Crm::Message.new(self.class, 'User', user&.id)
  end

  def call
    # validations
    refresh_authorization_code
  end

  def refresh_authorization_code
    response = RestClient.post(url, authorization_params)
    logger.info(@message.api_response(response))
    handle_response(response)
  end

  private

  attr_reader :user, :logger, :access_token, :refresh_token

  def handle_response(response)
    parsed = JSON.parse(response)
    user.update!(access_token: parsed[:access_token], refresh_token: parsed[:refresh_token])
  end
end
```

Also I tried using something like this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306038/using-rspec-to-test-a-retry-block-in-a-rescue)

```rb
 errors_to_raise = 2
allow(RestClient).to receive(:get) do
  return rest_response if errors_to_raise <= 0
  errors_to_raise -= 1
  raise RestClient::Unauthorized
end
# ...
expect(client_response.code).to eq(200)
```

but I don't know how handle it propertly.

Comment: You mock `RestClient.post`, could you show us the code where that is called? You're testing that `user.reload.access_token` changed, but I don't see any code which is changing `user.access_token`; could you show us the code that's supposed to do that?

Comment: I added more information but the problem is with the test, I know my code works, I just want to figure out how to test with rspec

Comment: If we can't see the code, we can't help test it. It seems `RestClient.post` is supposed to be called inside `Create#call` and the exception caught, but there's no call there. I *do* see a call to `RestClient.post` in `Refrfesh#token_refreshed`, there the exception will *not* be caught. It seems you need to mock *two* calls to `RestClient.post`, an auth failure inside `Create#call` and a successful one inside `Refresh#token_refreshed`; but without seeing your code that's just a guess.

Comment: I undertand @Schwern please take a look again to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test calls `RestClient.post` twice, first in `Create` then again in `Retry`. But you only mocked one call. You need to mock both calls. The first call raises an exception, the second responds with a successful result.

We could do this by specifying an order with [`ordered`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-10/docs/setting-constraints/message-order)...

```
context 'when token is expired' do
  it 'request a refresh token and retry' do
    old_key = user.access_token
    
    # First call fails
    allow(RestClient)
      .to receive(:post)
      .and_raise(RestClient::Unauthorized)
      .ordered
    
    # Second call succeeds and returns an auth response.
    # You need to write up that auth_response.
    # Alternatively you can .and_call_original but you probably
    # don't want your tests making actual API calls.
    allow(RestClient)
      .to receive(:post)
      .and_return(auth_response)
      .ordered

    expect { Create.new.call }.to change { user.reload.access_token }.from(old_key)
  end
end
```

However, this makes a lot of assumptions about exactly how the code works, and that nothing else calls `RestClient.post`.

More robust would be to use `with` to specify responses with specific arguments, and also verify the correct arguments are being passed.

```
context 'when token is expired' do
  it 'request a refresh token and retry' do
    old_key = user.access_token
    
    # First call fails
    allow(RestClient)
      .to receive(:post)
      .with(...whatever the arguments are...)
      .and_raise(RestClient::Unauthorized)
    
    # Second call succeeds and returns an auth response.
    # You need to write up that auth_response.
    # Alternatively you can .and_call_original but you probably
    # don't want your tests making actual API calls.
    allow(RestClient)
      .to receive(:post)
      .with(...whatever the arguments are...)
      .and_return(auth_response)

    expect { Create.new.call }.to change { user.reload.access_token }.from(old_key)
  end
end
```

But this still makes a lot of assumptions about exactly how the code works, and you need to make a proper response.

Better would be to focus in on exactly what you're testing: when the create call gets an unauthorized exception it tries to refresh and does the call again. This unit test doesn't have to also test that `Refresh#call` works, just that `Create#call` calls it. You don't need to have `RestClient.post` raise an exception, just that `Create#create_contact` does.

```
context 'when token is expired' do  
  it 'requests a refresh token and retry' do
    old_key = user.access_token
    create = Create.new(user)
    
    # First call fails
    allow(create)
      .to receive(:create_contact)
      .and_raise(RestClient::Unauthorized)
      .ordered

    # It refreshes
    refresh = double
    expect(Refresh)
      .to receive(:new)
      .with(user)
      .and_return(refresh)

    # The refresh succeeds
    expect(refresh)
      .to receive(:call)
      .with(no_args)
      .and_return(true)

    # It tries again
    expect(create)
      .to receive(:create_contact)
      .ordered
    
    create.call
  end
end
```

And you can also test when the retry fails. These can be combined together.

```
context 'when token is expired' do
  let(:refresh) { double }
  let(:create) { Create.new(user) }
  
  before {
    # First call fails
    allow(create)
      .to receive(:create_contact)
      .and_raise(RestClient::Unauthorized)
      .ordered
    
    # It tries to refresh
    expect(Refresh)
      .to receive(:new)
      .with(user)
      .and_return(refresh)
  }
  
  context 'when the refresh succeeds' do
    before {
      # The refresh succeeds
      allow(refresh)
        .to receive(:call)
        .with(no_args)
        .and_return(true)
    }
  
    it 'retries' do
      expect(create)
        .to receive(:create_contact)
        .ordered
      
      create.call
    end
  end
  
  context 'when the refresh fails' do
    before {
      # The refresh succeeds
      allow(refresh)
        .to receive(:call)
        .with(no_args)
        .and_return(false)
    }
  
    it 'does not retry' do
      expect(create)
        .not_to receive(:create_contact)
        .ordered
      
      create.call
    end
  end
end
```